# mocking an Eloquent collection

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, eloquent

I would like, *for crazy no point in explaining reasons*, to create a mock Eloquent Collection

I have tried this:

```
        $collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection(
            array(
                new User( array( "id" => 1 ) ),
                new User( array( "id" => 2 ) ),
                new User( array( "id" => 3 ) ),
                new User( array( "id" => 4 ) ),
                new User( array( "id" => 5 ) )
            )
        );

        $collection->get(); // Fails
```

but it turns out that this collection does not have a `->get()` method like it normally does when you'd do, something like:

```
User::take( 2 )->get();
```

*this ends up being because the \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection is just a namespaced and used \Illuminate\Database\Collection*

**any ideas how to mock an Eloquent Collection that actually works properly?**

Comment: There's no `get` on the collection. It's a `Query\Builder` method, that is called through the `Eloquent\Builder` (and through the `User` model in you example). Collection is a result of the `get` call in this case. Raw `Query\Builder` would return an array.

Answer (score 6):

I found out you can take the type of model you want to create and call `newCollection` on it.

```
$collection = new \User();
$collection->newCollection(
    array(
        new User( array( "id" => 1 ) ),
        new User( array( "id" => 2 ) ),
        new User( array( "id" => 3 ) ),
        new User( array( "id" => 4 ) ),
        new User( array( "id" => 5 ) )
    )
);
```

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_newCollection